# Exit a NSThread when it's sleeping?

Tags: ios, nsthread

I am creating a new Thread which runs one of my method:
Now what i am doing is as follows:

```
NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(myThreadFunc) object:nil];
[thread start];
```

in myThreadFunc

```
{
     while(isRunning){
         [self updateSomething];
         [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];
     }
     NSLog(@"out");
}
```

In another func,i set `isRunning = NO` and `thread = nil` or `[thread cancel]` but `myThreadFunc` is sleeping so thread cannot exit.
How can i control this case?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a thread. Use a timer. If the *something* is expensive, dispatch it off to some queue other than the main queue and set some state variable to show it's still running (if the *something* isn't meant to run concurrently). Then, just cancel your timer. A simple example of the timer call-back function might be:

```
- (void)doSomething:(NSTimer*)timer
{
  // this assumes that this "something" only ever
  // runs once at a time no matter what, adjust this
  // to an ivar if it's per-class instance or something
  static BOOL alreadyDoingSomething = NO;
  if( alreadyDoingSomething ) return;
  alreadyDoingSomething = YES;
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self updateSomething];
    alreadyDoingSomething = NO;
  });
}
```

Now, if you simply cancel the timer, this will stop running. When you're ready to start it again, schedule a new timer with this method as the designated selector. To make this behave similar to your example above, you might set the timer interval to three seconds.